# App_Code Function Issues: Label ID not being found/declared in App_Code Function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, app-code

This function works perfectly in my code behind page but I need to access this function globally.. So I move it to the app_code folder. Now, I am a bit lost on how to declare my label ID in a way that my new app_code File function finds it.

my error message = Error    35  'Label1' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
note: i do not not get this error in my code behind file

Thnx

Namespace BranchHours
    Public Class branchHours

```
    ' Public Shared Property Label1 As Object


    Public Shared Function MyFunc(ByVal branchCode As String) As String

        Dim URLString As String = "url/branchesTesting.xml"
        Dim xmlDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(URLString)
        ' Dim root As XmlNode = xmlDoc.DocumentElement
        '    Dim hoursList As XmlNodeList = root.SelectNodes("/BranchesInfo/BranchInfo[BranchId='db']/BranchHours/Hours")

        Dim x As Integer = 0 'looping variable

        Dim branchid = xmlDoc.XPathSelectElements("/BranchesInfo/BranchInfo[BranchId='" & branchCode & "']/BranchHours/Hours")
        Dim branchname = xmlDoc.XPathSelectElements("/BranchesInfo/BranchInfo[BranchId='" & branchCode & "'/Name]/BranchHours/Hours")

        Dim Items = From BranchHours In xmlDoc.XPathSelectElements("/BranchesInfo/BranchInfo[BranchId='" & branchCode & "']/BranchHours/Hours") _
        Select DayOfWeek = BranchHours.Element("DayOfWeek").Value, Open = BranchHours.Element("Open").Value, _
        Close = BranchHours.Element("Close").Value

        Label1.Text = ""
        For Each Hours In Items
            ' If x = 0 Then
            '  Label1.Text = Label1.Text & "<div>DayOfWeek:" & Hours.DayOfWeek & "</div>" + vbLf
            Label1.Text = Label1.Text & "<div>DayOfWeek:" & Hours.DayOfWeek & "</div>" + vbLf
            Label1.Text = Label1.Text & "Open: " & Hours.Open + vbLf
            Label1.Text = Label1.Text & "Close: " & Hours.Close + vbLf

            '    Else
            '     x = x + 1
            ' End If
        Next

        If Label1.Text = "" Then
            Label1.Text = "No Results."
        End If
        Return Label1.Text
    End Function


End Class
```

End Namespace

```
Public Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Call BranchHours.branchHours.MyFunc("dr")

    Label1.Text = BranchHours.branchHours.MyFunc("dr")




End Sub







 <%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default3bh.aspx.vb" Inherits="Default3bh" %>

  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"  For="label1"></asp:Label>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="AdditionalContent" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Instead of using Label1 in the method you should create a string variable and return it from the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in comments by Chetan Ranpariya
Instead of using Label1 in the method you should create a string variable and return it from the method – Chetan Ranpariya